# Circular reference in vue/vuex/router. Warning by jest

Tags: node.js, vue.js, jestjs, vuex, vue-router

Error triggered only while running jest  ( the bundle builds succefully without console errors )

```js
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

      1 | import { ServiceFactory } from '@/api/serviceFactory'
      2 |
    > 3 | const userService = ServiceFactory.get('users')
        |                                    ^
      4 | const authService = ServiceFactory.get('auth')
      5 |
      6 | const state = {

      at Object.<anonymous> (resources/src/store/modules/user.js:3:36)
      at Object.<anonymous> (resources/src/store/index.js:5:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (resources/src/api/axiosInstance.js:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (resources/src/api/entities/activities.js:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (resources/src/api/serviceFactory.js:1:1)
      at resources/src/components/DeleteEntity.vue:22:1
      at Object.<anonymous> (resources/src/components/DeleteEntity.vue:95:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (resources/src/tests/DeleteEntity.spec.js:2:1)
```

> DeleteEntity.vue is the component being tested. It imports the ServiceFactory

```js
import { ServiceFactory } from '@/api/serviceFactory'
const services = ServiceFactory.getAll()
```

> The serviceFactory has a list of all existing entities services starting with the activities.js ( logged in the error)

```js
const entities = {
  activities,
  activitiesCategories,
  address,
  auth,
  ...
}
```

> inside activities.js I import the axiosInstance all use in all my routes

```js
import axiosInstance from '../axiosInstance'

export default {
  create(){
    return axiosInstance.post(`/api/activities`)
  }
```

> inside axiosInstance.js I use interceptors to define my global axios instance and import my entry vuex store with all modules ( to commit logout ) and my router ( to redirect in case of error )

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { store } from '@/store/index'
import router from '@/routes/index'

const api = axios.create()

api.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('TOKEN_KEY')
    if (store.getters.isUserLogged) {
      config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token
    } else {
      store.commit('LOG_USER', false)
    }
    return config
  },
  error => {
    Promise.reject(error)
  }
)

api.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 201) {
      return Promise.resolve(response)
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(response)
    }
  },
  error => {
    if (error.response && error.response.status) {
      switch (error.response.status) {
        case 401:
          localStorage.removeItem('TOKEN_KEY')
          store.commit('LOG_USER', false)
          router.push('/login')
          break
        case 403:
          router.push({ name: '403' })
          break
        case 500:
          router.push({ name: '500' })
          break
      }
      return Promise.reject(error.response)
    }
  }
)
export default api
```

> Inside my router/index I import all my modules

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Ui from './modules/ui' <--- doesnt import serviceFactory inside it
import Auth from './modules/auth' <--- doesnt import serviceFactory inside it
import User from './modules/user' <--- import serviceFactory inside it and trigger the error
....
```

```js
import { ServiceFactory } from '@/api/serviceFactory'

const userService = ServiceFactory.get('users')
const authService = ServiceFactory.get('auth')
```

It creates a circular dependency  ( at least I think so )

```
1.serviceFactory -> 2.axiosInstance -> 3.vuexModules[firstThatImportServiceFactory] -> 4.serviceFactory -> 5.axiosInstance -> 6.vuexModules[secondThatImportServiceFactory] -> ....
```

Comment: How could I fix this? My first solution is just to remove all the serviceFactory references in vuex files ( but that will be a real heavy work ) Some ideas?

Comment: I feel like it's not the job of you AxiosInstance.js to deal with the router and vuex. 
I think that you should withdraw the router logic from axiosInstance and to keep it cohesive.